# wordpress bootstrap navbar is always expanded

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I built a static bootstrap website and the nav-bar was working fine but in the process of converting to wordpress template I have stumbled across an issue and can't figure it out.

Basically, when the navbar collapses to fit correct screen width the navbar menu is always expanded and the toggle button does not toggle to hide/show either.

Here is my full navbar HTML code:

```
  <div id="navbar-wrapper" class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
         <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img class="logo" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/logo_blue_ls.png" alt="Relax on Ryan"></a>    
                </div><!-- navbar header -->

                <!-- if the menu (WP admin area) is not set, then the "menu_class" is applied to "container". IN other words, it overwrites the "container_class". Ref: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-nav-menu-class-usage-bug?replies=4 -->

                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(

                        'theme_location'    =>  'primary',
                        'container'         =>  'nav',
                        'container _class'  =>  'navbar-collapse collapse',
                        'menu_class'        =>  'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

                    ) );
                ?>

            </div><!-- navbar-container -->
        </div><!-- navbar-inner -->
    </div><!-- navbar -->   
 </div><!-- navbar-wrapper -->
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated. I was wondering if my data-target may be incorrectly defined?

Thanks,
Heath

Comment: You're missing `'container_id'      => 'navbar'` inside your array (the reason it won't exapand and collapse) and ``container _class`` appears to have a space before the underscore (this may be from copying and pasting though). See [Bootstrap Navwalker](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

Comment: Thanks vanburen. All sorted. I checked my code so many times and still missed that space....

Comment: No problem and you should consider removing your question since this was a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="navbar-wrapper" class="navbar-wrapper">
   <nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
         <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
         <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>

              <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                 <img id="logo" src="{logo}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
              </a>
         </div>
         <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
            'menu'            => 'primary',
            'theme_location'  => 'primary',
            'depth'           => 2,
            'container'       => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
            'container_id'    => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
            ));
         ?>
      </div><!-- /.container -->
   </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Some explanation as to why this is the solution to the OPs problem wuld be good.